# Problem by building the hector_lokalization package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I tried to build the hector_localization package but could not. Im using Ubuntu 10.04 and ROS Fuerte. I got the following error.

```
Error: package/stack hector_pose_estimation_rtt depends on non-existent package rtt_rosnode
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
    'hector_pose_estimation_rtt'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.
    Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!
```

Any help??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51354/problem-by-building-the-hector_lokalization-package/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you need to install rtt. Try:

sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-rtt-*

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2013-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-01-02**:
I cant. It gives me an error E: Couldn't find package ros-fuerte-rtt-*